# how to find out whether a point is surrounded by other points

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I want to find out if a point $(x, y)$ is surrounded by a set of points.

To understand my problem a short explanation:

I am a programmer and I have a function for the user to select objects by drawing around the object with his/her finger. When the user is finished, I get a list of points with the user's touch-points. basically i want to find out if a point is surround by a polygon

Hope you can help me.

Pic:[PointA (Pa) is Surrounded by other points (P1, P2 .... Pn), now i want to finde out finde out whether that point is surrounded by that point or not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuWw2.jpg)

Comment: Is $(x/y)$ computer programming notation for the point $(x, y)$ of the coordinate plane?  It sounds like you wish to determine if the selected points are within a defined radius of a given point, that is, within a circle of radius $r$ with center at the given point.

Comment: i mentioned the (x,y) to show that the Coordinators are 2D. i need something like whether a point is between 2 other points.

Comment: When you say it is between two other points, do you mean that it is on the line segment connecting those points?

Comment: I think the question is asking if point $(x,y)$ is within the convex hull of a set of points. Or perhaps within the polygon defined by an ordered set of points.

Comment: i have added i picture to describe what i need to do.

think that convex hull  is what iam looking for but i have still know i idea how it works.

Comment: It seems more likely you're asking whether your point is _within a particular polygon_. (Though the yellow line you have drawn seems to be slightly too smoothed for that).

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes that is what iam trying to do, any suggestions how i could do that?